# My accounts aren't showing up on meta.SO

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, linked-accounts

When I go to [my meta.SO account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/161783/zev-chonoles?tab=accounts), I am told that I have no associated accounts:

[image]

But on any of my other local account pages (e.g. [my main account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/264/zev-chonoles?tab=accounts) on math.SE), as well as my [global SE account](https://stackexchange.com/users/505899?tab=accounts), I can see all of my other accounts, **including my meta.SO account**. So they definitely are associated; it just seems like the meta.SO account page is unaware. I can't find any action I can take to attempt to fix this, nor does searching on meta.SO seem to turn up any instances of this exact problem, so if someone could help my accounts show up here, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Same here. Maybe this should have been reported in this "question": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112151/new-user-page-live-on-meta

Comment: @Mat you mean [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112877/152859)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: not really. It doesn't show _any_ account for anyone right now (summary or account tab) in my browser anyway. According to your user profile right now, you don't have any accounts either.

Comment: @Mat yeah, it worked fine yesterday though. So guess it's like the avatars that vanished some time ago - some global temporary glitch that will be fixed soon.

Comment: It _was_ showing initially when they first rolled out the new profile page, now it's not. Maybe it's a different issue.

Comment: I see no accounts, but I see the "Copy Meta Stack Overflow profile to all Stack Exchange accounts" button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now fixed, a build for the API backing that call was just pushed out.

---

And because programmer love some behind the scenes info porn, here goes:

The reason the user page isn't live yet for normal users on Stack Overflow is that we're still making some performance optimizations around the changes.  One of the expensive things the profile has is the Accounts tab and panel (we call the sections on the summary tab "panels").

Originally, we had/have data for the accounts/users aggregated up to the network level in a single database, but not *all* of the data, namely: badges, and last visited and joined dates were missing.  This means the accounts tab itself has to go visit various site databases and do a measurable amount of work.  [Kevin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose) added badges to the aggregator which means everything we need *for the panel* could skip that per-site database user query, everything we needed was in the network database.

Further optimizing this, we only need to return the top 5 accounts/users + a count of total accounts/users (the count was added after we realized showing 5 was a glitch, and we only need 5 because the accounts tab shows more data which needs another API call anyway).  However, this is a JSON API of simple data.  And... *unless you build that service with the new code* (oops, my bad), that property won't be on the result...and the client deserailizing it into a class gets a 0 (default) on that property...resulting in what you saw, a 0 account list.

Comment: What about `area51`? It still doesn't show [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard?tab=accounts) while showing in the [old profile design](http://stackoverflow.com/users/447356/shadow-wizard?tab=accounts)

Comment: @Shadow - hmmm we don't aggregate area51, I'll look into it

Comment: +1 for unnessecary details

Comment: Thanks @Nick there is also [this pending post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112947/152859) where I initially saw the problem.