# What's up with the "0 accounts"?

Tags: bug, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Other Stack Exchange accounts are not shown in my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136368/other-stack-exchange-accounts-are-not-shown-in-my-profile)

In my profile, it now says I have a total of 0 accounts. What happened?

I see this is a duplicate of [My accounts aren't showing up on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113195/174847) , but that one was marked as solved in November last year. So has the problem returned, or is this a new one?

Comment: It says "[___] temporarily unavailable" for everything related to the Stack Exchange account, guess they're doing some major change.

Comment: And it's solved now.

Comment: Yes it is, wonder why no mod marked the "main" report as resolved.

Comment: Still [not completely solved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136417/account-page-incorrectly-showing-0-answers) guess that's why it's not marked as [meta-tag:status-completed] then.