# Account page incorrectly showing 0 answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Other Stack Exchange accounts are not shown in my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136368/other-stack-exchange-accounts-are-not-shown-in-my-profile)

The site-wide [accounts page](https://stackexchange.com/users/286976/pubby?tab=accounts) is showing 0 answers:

```
Stack Overflow
Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers
Joined 1 year ago, last seen today
12,506 reputation
2 21 48 badges
62 questions 0 answers
             ^^^^^^^^^
```

This is clearly incorrect as I have [351 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964135/pubby?tab=answers).

Comment: The problem is much larger than just that one number. The accounts API was down earlier, so all the values are probably still updating or something. I'm sure Tim Stone will pop in and explain it.

Comment: The problem behind the scenes is the same hence voting to close - I'm pretty sure that once the other one will be fixed this one will be also fixed.

Comment: I have the opposing problem, uniquely. I have Answers on [so] but 0's for all other accounts.

Comment: No, the accounts page shows *good* answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed now. A backfill over the weekend wasn't correctly executed, leaving the `QuestionCount` and `AnswerCount` columns empty. Thanks for the report.

Comment: I now have equal questions and answers..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry about that. This bug existed for people with 0 questions and more than 0 answers on a site. It's fixed now (old values may be cached for up to 5 minutes from now though).

Comment: Thanks, looks solved now. :-)

Comment: @Emmett It is still not solved I guess. I'm writing this after around 8 years. I'm facing this incorrect answer count issue.