# Stack exchange profile, account tab, not showing answer and question totals?

Tags: bug, user-accounts, network-profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Account page incorrectly showing 0 answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136417/account-page-incorrectly-showing-0-answers)

I noticed that all the totals for questions and answers seem to have been reset to 0 on the accounts tab of my profile page:

https://stackexchange.com/users/322227/antonchanning?tab=accounts

An answer I posted earlier in English has shown up, but no older ones.  I checked another users profile and all their totals have been reset to 0 also.  Is this a bug or is there some legitimate explanation for why this should be?

Comment: This is happening to me too currently, the API was down a couple of days ago so this could be a reoccurrence.

Comment: There we go - [original bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136417/account-page-incorrectly-showing-0-answers)

Comment: @Rory Thanks.  For some reason I couldn't find that when I was searching for explanations. o.O