# Question and answer counts on my network profile are wrong

Tags: bug, network-profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Stack exchange profile, account tab, not showing answer and question totals?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136565/stack-exchange-profile-account-tab-not-showing-answer-and-question-totals)

[My network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/505899/zev-chonoles?tab=accounts) currently lists the number of questions I've asked as 0 for every site I have an account on, and the number of answers I've posted as 0 for every site (except Mathematics). Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I'm using Chrome 19.0.1084.56 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: I'd say this is a dupe of [Stack exchange profile, account tab, not showing answer and question totals?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136565)

Comment: Ah, thanks for your help. I've voted to close as a duplicate.

Comment: This one is solved? Because mine is still showing the answer count lesser by 1.