# Answer count in network profile is less than the actual count

Tags: bug, answers, network-profile

My [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/4412195/behaviour?tab=accounts) cites the number of answers on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) that is consistently less (by 13) than the actual number, shown on my [site profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/147263/behaviour?tab=answers). Over the time, the counts changed as:

- network profile: 1306; site profile: 1319
- network profile: 1313; site profile: 1326
- ...
- network profile: 1527; site profile: 1540

Some other users are similarly affected:

- Daniel Fischer: [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/996105/daniel-fischer?tab=accounts) states 6 answers fewer than  [Math site profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer)
- Qiaochu Yuan: [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/127441/qiaochu-yuan?tab=accounts) states 4 answers fewer than [Math site profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/232/qiaochu-yuan).

There are [similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136573/) [reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180368/), but they are either marked completed, or describe a different situation (migrated posts). I thought that CW answers could explain the discrepancy, but I have 112 of those, not 13.

Comment: Caching, it's always caching. :/

Comment: Well, the reputation on the same page is up to date...

Comment: Yeah, Stack Exchange is using ultra-complicated caching to boost up speed. It works awesome 99.999% of the times, but with millions of users and billions of requests, things sometimes break. Probably a "hard reset" for your cache will fix this issue, but only a dev can do it.

Comment: I have a difference of 1. The most recent question / answer was 4 days ago, so this caching has quite severe.

Comment: Just some thought, does it really matter if 13 answers were missing from the count, it is not like half of them aren't sowing.