# Account in Network Profile missing posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, network-profile

I had an account on Stack Overflow, and when I wanted to post on Super User, I went on to create another account before realising that those could be linked together. Now when I go to my [Network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/4060511/bilbo-pingouin?tab=accounts), I can see a link to my Super User account, but it states that I haven't posted any question or answer:

> [image]

However when I have a look at [my account on Super User](https://superuser.com/users/389078/bilbo-pingouin), I can see the question that prompted me to log in superuser in the first place:

> [image]

I contacted the SE Team and got the response

> This is a problem we're aware of, since it happens more frequently than we'd like it to. We're currently working on a solution for this problem, but it might take some time before it is rolled out.
>
> I've had a look at [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), and it does not look like there's a bug report for this yet. As such, it could also be useful if you created a post there to have this problem documented.

That documentation is, therefore the main reason for this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All fixed, sorry about that.

The full fix alluded to in the email you got is something that, honestly, is pretty low priority right now. For the moment, we're just fixing these issues as we come across them since they're all pretty straightforward.

Comment: I posted the same thing [last year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245060/): missing 13 answers in the network profile count. Got 12 upvotes in compensation...